# "Uncaught Syntaxerror: Unexpected Identifier" with unbind

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a "uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected identifier" on line:

`$(‘form#GoogleForm’).unbind('submit').submit();`

Here is my jquery code:

```
$(function(){
//original field values
var field_values = {
        //id        :  value
        'fullname'  : 'full name',
        'companyname'  : 'company name',
        'email'  : 'email address'
};

$('#toggleCheck').change(function(){
    $('#toggleDiv').toggle();
});

//inputfocus
$('input#companyname').inputfocus({ value: field_values['companyname'] });
$('input#fullname').inputfocus({ value: field_values['fullname'] });
$('input#email').inputfocus({ value: field_values['email'] }); 

//first_step
$('form#GoogleForm').submit(function(){ return false; });
$('#submit_first').click(function(){
    //remove classes
    $('#first_step input').removeClass('error').removeClass('valid');

    //ckeck if inputs aren't empty or invalid
    var fields = $('#first_step input[type=text]');
    var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
    var error = 0;
    fields.each(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        if( value.length<2 || value==field_values[$(this).attr('id')] || ( $(this).attr('id')=='email' && !emailPattern.test(value) ) ) {
            $(this).addClass('error');
            $(this).effect("shake", { times:3 }, 40);

            error++;
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('valid');
        }
    });        

    if(!error) {
        //slide steps
        $('#first_step').hide();
        $('#second_step').show();     
    } else return false;

});

// second step
$('#submit_second').click(function(){

    //prepare the third step
    var fields = new Array(
        $('#fullname').val(),
        $('#companyname').val(),
        $('#email').val()                      
    );
    var tr = $('#third_step tr');
    tr.each(function(){
        //alert( fields[$(this).index()] )
        $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').html(fields[$(this).index()]);
    });

    //slide steps
    $('#second_step').hide();
    $('#third_step').show();            
});

//third step
$('#submit_third').click(function(){
    //send information to server
    $(‘form#GoogleForm’).unbind('submit').submit();
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

In the line `$(‘form#GoogleForm’).unbind('submit').submit();` you use no valid quotes. You have to use `'form#GoogleForm'` or `"form#GoogleForm"` instead of `‘form#GoogleForm’`.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you retype the single quotes, it'll work. It appears to be a different character right now.